# Structuring the table of a multi-lingual dictionary database

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

I want to structure the table(s) for the database of a multi-lingual dictionary (English - Marathi). [Marathi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathi_language) is a regional language in India.
The format of the dictionary is:

> word | english_meaning1 | marathi_meaning1 | english_meaning2 |
>   marathi_meaning2 **...** english_meaningN | marathi_meaningN

Words can have variable number of pairs of english and marathi meanings depending upon whether it belongs to any of the lexical categories (Noun, Adverb, Verb, Adjective etc.) 
Currently I have thought of an inefficient approach of creating a table like this:

**Table**: word

- **word_id**
- word
- english_meaning1
- marathi_meaning1
- english_meaning2
- marathi_meaning2
- english_meaning3
- marathi_meaning3
- english_meaning4
- marathi_meaning4

  **.

  .

  .

  .**
- english_meaning10
- marathi_meaning10

Here I am assuming a fixed number of columns (20) for english and marathi meanings for a word in English. So if a word has only a single meaning (in English & Marathi), the rest of the columns will remain empty.

Also, if it's a word for example: 'about', which in the dictionary is shown as:

> about1 - meanings
>  about2 - meanings

Then I'm maintaining them as separate rows in the above structured table.
Isn't this approach problematic? Can this be solved by normalizing it? I have thought of a way
where the tables will be: 
Table: **word**

- **word_id**
- word

Table: **word_english**

- **id**
- word_id (FK from word table)
- english_meaning

Table: **word_marathi**

- **id**
- word_id
- marathi_meaning

I am not pretty sure whether the above approach makes sense. Could anyone suggest a possible solution?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ooof.  definitely normalize

```
word
---------
word_id
word
definition
language_id
lexical_part_id

language
-----------
language_id
name

word_word
------------
word1_id
word2_id

lexical_part
-------------
lexical_part_id
name
```

then fill in the word_word table with the equivalence map

Comment: could you please explain the purpose of the table word_word? I didn't get that part.

Comment: ok - let's say word one is 'don' with id 1, and another word is 'two' with id 2 - you want to declare equivalence by entering a row in word_word with word1_id = 1 and word2_id = 2.  later you will ask - what are all the words equivalent to 'don' by SELECT word2_id FROM word_word where word1_id = 1